# jquery mobile cannot hide submit button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using the latest version of jquery mobile and my problem is that I have given a submit button an ID and then added some css to set the ID to display:none;

For some reason this does not work.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do without any code but I think the problem stems from the fact that jQuery Mobile doesn't style your existing button but rather, hides the element and wraps it in a new `div` which is styled to look and behave like a button.

The current jQuery Mobile markup for a button looks like this:

```
<div data-theme="e" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-hover-e ui-btn-down-e" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Submit</span>
    </span>
    <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" data-theme="e" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false">
</div>
```

So you look for the closest ancestor with the class `ui-btn` and hide it:

```
$('#submit_btn').closest('.ui-btn').hide();
```

If there's a better way to do this, I'd love to know about it. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/vZ4SA/) that shows my solution in action.

Comment: This requires the page to load first though. Not ideal for a button you don't want displayed. I'm having the same issue..

Comment: A better solution: `<input type="submit" data-role="none" style="display:none;">`

Answer (score 21):

I always use:

```
$("#<button-id>").parent().hide();
```

It seems to work fine as the button or input element will always be a child of the 'wrapper' div.

Comment: For safety, I use .parents('.ui-btn').hide(). Just in case new versions or unforeseen circumstances will make the <button> not a child but a grandchild of the <div>.

Answer (score 11):

I've had issues with the above answers in cases i needed to toggle between the states.

I found it easiest to wrap your initial button in a div and then just hide/show it.

Meaning :

```
<div id="someid">
<input type="button" class="submit_button" id="resend_invoice" value="Button"/>
</div>
```

And then simply addressing the containing div would work as usual, as all the jQuery mobile divs and classes are created inside the containing div.

Comment: This is simplest solution that works great. You can then manipulate the containing div to hide or show the button whenever you want.

Answer (score 4):

If you add `data-role="none"` to your input element, then jQuery mobile will not draw the extra button.

Comment: There is a place in heaven for you. Fixed bunch of things for me, thanks alot.