# jQuery Mobile - Cannot hide a button using common jquery methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have this very simple button that I would like to hide

```
<input type="button" id="logoutBtn" value="logout" 
       data-theme="d" data-inline="true" aria-disabled="false">
```

I am using this simple call to try and hide it but it does not do anything

```
$('#logoutBtn').hide();
```

So then I tried adding this, which does not work either.

```
$('#first').live('pageinit', function(e){
      $('#logoutBtn').hide();
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the button located in the page? Is it created at runtime? What is '#first'?

Comment: Must be <div id="first"><input type="button" id="logoutBtn".../></div>

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053335.  This other question has several answers, each shows a different way to hide an element.  Pick the one that's best for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery mobile cannot hide submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053335/jquery-mobile-cannot-hide-submit-button)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [jquery mobile cannot hide submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053335/jquery-mobile-cannot-hide-submit-button)

```
<div data-theme="e" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-hover-e ui-btn-down-e" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Submit</span>
    </span>
    <input type="submit" id="logoutBtn" value="button" data-theme="e" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false">
</div>

$('#logoutBtn').closest('.ui-btn').hide();
```

Comment: A better solution: `<input type="submit" data-role="none" style="display:none;">`