# Submit form with enter key/hide submit button

Tags: jquery

I am making a little jquerymobile page with a single input field to do a database search. The input is being done by a barcode reader that presses enter at the end. I would like to hide the submit button and have the form submit with the enter key.

Ive tried bits and pieces of code read in other threads, but with no avail. Im a dunce when it comes to javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').hide();
    });
$('.noEnterSubmit').keypress(function(e){
    if ( e.which == 13 ) 
    $('form#search').submit();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
</script>
```

on top of that I have a button that focuses on the input field when pressed (because on iOS devices you cant force focus onload)

```
<form action="#CGI.SCRIPNAME#" method="post" name="search">
<label for="season_pass_id">Season Pass ID</label>
<input class="noEnterSubmit" type="password" name="season_pass_id">
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
<input type="button" name="mybutton" value="Scan New" OnClick="document.search.season_pass_id.focus();">
</form>
```

ultimately I would love to hide the input field and the submit button and only have the "Scan New" button

Comment: is it possible to detecta new line char? When it get detected you can fire up the submit function

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your keypress code into the `document.ready` handler. I'm suspecting the dom element has not loaded when you're attaching the event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').hide();
    $('.noEnterSubmit').keypress(function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); 
       if ( e.which == 13 ) 
        $('form#search').submit();    
    });
});
```

Comment: I found this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053335/jquery-mobile-cannot-hide-submit-button) and used `$('#submit_btn').parents('.ui-btn').hide();`.  It successfully hides the submit button, but on first submission of the form, the page reloads and shows the submit button again. on second submission of the form it gives me my results and the submit button. so odd

Comment: I ended up going to an ajax post method to maintain my focus on the input field. I would still like to see a solution to this question though.