# jQuery(Mobile): button not hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm facing a very weird problem. here is my code:

```
<div id="status">
        <div id="armStatus">
            <div id="armText">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>Unit</legend>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="CB" name="armCB_1" id="armCB_1" class="custom" data-mini="true" />
                    <label for="armCB_1">Arming Status</label>
                    <p id="armingtext"></p>
                </fieldset>
             </div>
        </div>
        <table class="config" id="status_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4"; style= "padding-bottom: 20px; color:#6666FF; text-align:left; font-size: 1.5em">Feedback Status</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Index</th>

                    <th>Feedback Type</th>
                    <th>Feedback Number</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th class="cHide">Monitor?</th>
                    <th class="cHide">Remove?</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 <tr>
                 </tr>
            </tbody>       
       </table>
       <button type="button" id="monitor" class="cHide" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-transition="fade">Monitor</button>

    </div>
```

As show above, the button `monitor` is having the same class `.cHide` as the 2 table headers `monitor?` and 'remove?`. but when this is called:

```
$(".cHide").hide();
```

Only the `monitor?` and `remove?` column is hidden but the `monitor` button is still there.
Why is that so? what's wrong?

EDIT: seems like it's working fine if it is standalone. I suspect will it be because of

```
 $('#monitor').button('enable');
```

placed somewhere?

here's part of the code where i hide and show `.cHide` (which is in the document.ready)

```
 $('.done').click(function(){
            $('#n_keypad').hide();
            login_code = $('#myInput').val();

            $.post( '/login' , {passcode:login_code.toString()})
                .done(function(reply) {
                    $("#login_div").hide();
                    alert("You are login as " + reply);
                    if (reply=="engineer"){
                         $("#securityMode").show();
                         $("#labels").show();
                         $("#status").show();
                         $("#display").show();                             
                         $("#logoutbutton").show();
                         $(".cHide").show();
                         $("#loginbutton").hide();
                         $("#configtable").hide();
                    }   
                    else if(reply=="user"){
                        $("#securityMode").show();                            
                        $("#configtable").show();
                        $("#logoutbutton").show();
                        $("#labels").hide();
                        $("#status").show();
                        $("#display").hide();
                        $("#configeditdiv").hide();                            
                        $(".cHide").hide();


                    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$(".cHide")` with a debugger? Code looks good so far.

Comment: Your code works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/JY2ub/. It's something outside of this that will be causing the problem.

Comment: are you using any UI frameworks? like jQuery UI or Mobile etc..

Comment: This code is working fine. Show your full jquery code

Comment: Time to learn how to set breakpoints in FireBug or Chrome developer tools

Comment: and what browser are you using?

Comment: Midori on Raspberry Pi

Comment: How can you not have used a debugger? What happens when you get errors?

Comment: @Zenith search lines by lines using my eyes @_@

Comment: @yvonnezoe but that gives you just a static view of your code

Comment: @asifrc yes jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Thought so :) what version, and where in your code do you call the `.hide()` function? (head, body/onload, onclick, etc.)

Comment: @asifrc i've edited the question to include that part of code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery Mobile has had problems hiding buttons, since the framework wraps the button in a styled div and hides the button (i.e. you're trying to hide a button that's already hidden). This problem has been addressed by this question: [jquery mobile cannot hide submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053335/jquery-mobile-cannot-hide-submit-button)

which would suggest that something like `$('.cHide').closest('.ui-btn').hide();` should work for you. Give it a try and let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

What hide will do is to set the style display property to none. Execute your code and with a debbuger tool (like chrome dev tool) inspect the element and see if the property is set on the button

Answer (score -1):

Try and hide the button using its ID. $("#monitor").hide()

Comment: thanks but tried ;) not working.